# Contour Integration of a simple expression

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let's calculate the integral
$$
\oint_\gamma \frac{e^{ikz}}{z} \, {\rm d} z
$$
where $k>0$ and $\gamma$ is the closed contour starting at $-\infty$ to $-\epsilon$, then the $\epsilon$ half-circle clockwise, from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$ and finally the half-circle counter-clockwise back to $-\infty$. The latter vanishes for obvious reasons. Since no pole is enclosed the entire contour integral is $0$. What remains is
$$
{\rm PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikz}}{z} \, {\rm d} z - \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{e^{ikz}}{z} \, {\rm d} z = 0
$$
where $\gamma_\epsilon$ is the $\epsilon$ half-circle counter-clockwise around $z=0$. The result of the ${\rm PV}$ is thus $i\pi$.
So far consistent...

Now let's deform the contour at $-\infty$ to bring it to $+\infty$ while encircling the pole at $z=0$. This can be done, because the integral over the big half-circle at $\infty$ vanishes, and no singularities are crossed. The result should therefore be same.
However the contour can now be closed at $+\infty$ and the residue-theorem gives $-2\pi i$. How is that?

Comment: What do you mean you can close the contour at $+\infty$?

Comment: The contour starts at $+\infty-i\epsilon$ and ends at $+\infty+i\epsilon$. The integral over length $2\epsilon$ at $+\infty$ gives no contribution.

Comment: Okay, so the integral deforms to a big counterclockwise circle and a small clockwise circle about the origin (the integral back and forth along the positive real axis cancels out). These give a $+2\pi i$ and a $-2\pi i,$ cancelling out to zero, which is what the original contour integral was

Comment: No. As I said, the contour starts at $+\infty -i\epsilon$ goes to $\epsilon$ below the x-axis, encircles the pole at $z=0$ clockwise and finally the integral goes back to $+\infty+i\epsilon$ above the x-axis.

Comment: I don't even see how you arrive at a big counterclockwise circle?!

Comment: Was imagining you were starting with the second image here and deforming to the third. https://goo.gl/images/h6bSme . Now I have no clue what deformation you're saying can happen. Could you explain your last paragraph again or draw it or something?

Comment: Hm.....Now I need my paint skills?
https://ibb.co/m7AqC8

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. But I assumed the original contour closed on top (so it would have no pole inside and integrate to zero like you described). These two both integrate to $-2\pi i.$

Comment: It did enclose on top. But it vanishes, so it doesn't matter. I don't need this contour.
However now that I think about it again, it might be due to the fact that I can only deform in the upper halfplane, because the arc in the lower halfplane does not vanish.

Comment: Yeah, erasing it and redrawing it below doesn't qualify as 'deforming'.. it's a drastic change in the topology (with respect to the pole at zero, which you'd have to go through). And you're right that the semicircle on the bottom doesn't go to zero, so you can't erase and redraw on those grounds.

Comment: @Diger Iooking at the comments it seems like  $\frac{e^{ikz}}{z} \, {\rm d} z$ what kind of contour would this be defined over  it seems like a semicircular contour would do the job? and also would it be reasonable to conjecture that  $\oint_\gamma \frac{e^{ikz}}{z} \, {\rm d} z = 2 \pi i$

Comment: Sorry I'm not on par...Is that a question and if yes what do you want to know? :-/
Any contour encircling zero would do the job. In my case above I did not encircle it in the first step though (using a big semicircle).